# Javascript variable update with other variable changes

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have three variables

```
var subTotalA = 5;
var subTotalB = 5;
var Total = subTotalA + subTotalB;
```

I am using subTotal in many places, and changes to the subtotal are applied in many different functions and different ways. Is there any way that I attach a function to subTotalA and SubTotalB to recalculate the Total whenever they change their value. I also want to be able to update the some html elements showing these values in the html pages.

Comment: Why don't you calculate total whenever you need instead of calculate it statically?

Comment: I can recalculate the Total whenever I change the subTotals, but the code is complex and I was looking for an elegant and simple way of attaching a function with a change in the value of a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a MV* framework, something like Knockout?

```js
function Model() {
  this.subTotalA = ko.observable(1);
  this.subTotalB = ko.observable(1);
  this.Total = ko.computed(function() {
    return this.subTotalA() + this.subTotalB();
  }, this);
}

var model = new Model();

ko.applyBindings(model);

setInterval(function() {
  model.subTotalA(model.subTotalA() + 1);
}, 1700);

setInterval(function() {
  model.subTotalB(model.subTotalB() + 1);
}, 1100);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
Subtotal A: <input data-bind="value: subTotalA" readonly><br>
Subtotal B: <input data-bind="value: subTotalB" readonly><br>
<hr>
The total is <span data-bind="text: Total">
```

Each time either of the subtotals is set (using `model.subTotalA(...)`), the computed property `Total` is updated, and also displayed. (With a bit more care regarding type conversion, it would even work if we let users type into the input boxes, the changes propagate automagically without you needing to explicitly write code for it.)

Yes, the syntax changes. Other MV* frameworks have less impact on syntax so you can [choose](http://todomvc.com/) whichever suits you best (but there is no framework that allows you to track changes to local variables, because there is no way to do that in JS to my knowledge).

Comment: What in the world does this question have to do with Knockout... or any framework for that matter?!

Comment: @Andrew: It does not yet - that is why I am proposing it. MV* frameworks are, if I understand what OP is doing, a perfect fit for his requirements: automatic propagation of calculation (not just to `Total`, but also to "I also want to be able to update the some html elements showing these values in the html pages.", in his words).

Comment: Wouldn't this answer would make a much better comment than it does a posted answer then?

Comment: @Andrew: Why? It solves the question. Just because the OP doesn't know this is what he needs, it doesn't make it less appropriate. I am not adding jQuery (the usual complaint) just because I am lazy - I am saying that this is a tool that is the best way to tackle the problem. If someone asks "how do you add two numbers", do you disallow "+" simply because the OP hasn't mentioned it? Besides, I couldn't demonstrate how it would work in a comment like I can in a code snippet.

Comment: @Amadan yes I am happy that you suggested this, because I was thinking there might be something listen to the change events on data variables just like jQuery does on html elements.

Comment: His question was, "can I have a variable update automatically when these other variables change." The answer is no, he'll need to do it manually. Knockout isn't tagged, either. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40987409/3421659) answer actually answers the OP's question.

Comment: @Andrew, don't be dense. I already addressed the fact that Knockout is not tagged: it is simply to be an example of application of any MV* framework solving the problem of automatic propagation of calculation. The answer is "use MV* framework", not "this is how you do it in Knockout". OP is clearly capable of articulating what his question is, as you can see in the comment just above yours: "something listen to the change events on data variables", which is textbook definition of data binding. I'd rather think that the linked answer doesn't answer the question: "whenever change their value".

Answer (score 4):

Why not use a function instead? Something like

```
function getTotal(a, b) {
  return a + b;
}
```

You can then use it like the following:

```
var subTotalA = 5;
var subTotalB = 5;
var Total = getTotal(subTotalA, subTotalB);
```

Comment: I can make this a function but the point is I will have to put a function call whenever there is a change in any subTotal. The existing code is changing the subTotals with some complex rules.

Comment: I doubt there's a way to get around that, unless you want to add a library to take care of events. This can get complicated pretty soon. You don't really have to 'do a function call whenever there is a change in any subTotal', you can just instead replace `Total` with a call to that function. Anywhere you reference `Total`, you can instead reference `getTotal(a, b)` to return the total at that point.

Comment: so how does it work if I am displaying Total in a div. Will it be updated automatically when subTotal change happens? I am new to JS and jQuery so I was looking for an elegant or an easy way of doing it.

Comment: @Novice you'll need to change the div contents yourself, or you can implement that into the function definition if you'd prefer

Answer (score 3):

I suggest making a reusable `updateTotal()` function and calling that or passing it as a callback whenever necessary.

But if you really want to go crazy, you could use a getter on an object to calculate the total.

```
const calculation = {};
Object.defineProperty(calculation, 'total', {
    enumerable : true,
    get : () => {
        return subTotalA + subTotalB;
    }
});
```

Now we never have to set `calculation.total`, just set the `subTotalA` and `subTotalB` variables and the total will be "updated" accordingly. Or rather, it will calculate the appropriate value on-demand.

```
subTotalA = 2;
subTotalB = 5;
console.log(calculation.total);  // => 7
subTotalB = 9;
console.log(calculation.total);  // => 11
```

Comment: using `defineProperty` can also help with the `update the some html elements showing these values` part of the question

Comment: @JaromandaX: Not in local variables, unfortunately. (Also, this is part of the reason I recommended a MV* framework - they handle this part for you.)

Comment: @Amadan - I know you are defending your answer, but I don't understand why you are responded negatively to my comment ... just because you don't know how to do it, doesn't mean it's not possible

Comment: @JaromandaX: Not negatively, just as a clarification of what you said. And if you do know how to use `defineProperty` to observe local variables, please do enlighten me. I'd say there isn't, because local variables aren't properties.

Comment: I see what you mean by local variables now. I meant another property on the calculation object in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Its simple

```
 <input type="text" id="txtSubTotalA" onkeyup="calculate()">
  <input type="text" id="txtSubTotalB" onkeyup="calculate()">
```

have a calculate function

```
function calculate() {
    var total = $('txtSubTotalA').val() + $('txtSubTotalB').val();
}
```

well for javascript

```
function calculate() {
        var total = document.getElementById("txtSubTotalA").value +      document.getElementById("txtSubTotalA").value;
    }
```

Comment: jQuery isn't tagged.

Comment: JQuery is tagged check again bro :D

Comment: It was not tagged when you posted this answer, only just now was the post edited, but okay

Answer (score 0):

use some object function like this

```js
var subTotalA = 5;
var subTotalB = 5;

var total = function(data)
            { 
              return data.a+data.b;
            }
console.log(total({'a':subTotalA,'b':subTotalB}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use react to use it 
useState is the best way to do it...

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const App = () => {

  const [x, setX] = useState(1),
       [y, setY] = useState(2);

      return (
          <div>
            { x + y }
          </div>
       )
}

export default App;
```